# API Centric web application in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Recently assigned to a new project where we need to build a api centric web application. Requirement is to build 2 separate projects in Laravel one the has all API's that can be accessed by either web or mobile applications(for future purpose) and other is a web application that uses the API's to work almost all of its function.

Building an API project in Laravel is a easy and lots of tutorials are available about using passport etc. But how do i implement that API to web application.

My major question is how do i setup authentication for web application using api, because its default authentication is model based, or my approach is wrong?

Please suggest ideas, because we are currently in planning phase.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Each Laravel Project will be identified as it's own "site" so the only suggestion I would have is if you plan to invoke your APIs via AJAX calls to be wary of Cross-Domain Scripting issues.

Comment: Implementing both as separate sites is the idea... www.abc.com and api.abc.com. Any other ideas you suggest?